# Admob 6.4.1 - Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, admob

When adding admob to my xml it causes a fatal error which leads to crash the application.

I added the admob jar correctly in /libs and to build path.

The xml looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView 
                        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
                         android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="#######"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="######"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/> </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is logcat

> 07-29 00:39:59.113: E/Ads(8849): Could not initialize AdView: AdView
>   was initialized with a Context that wasn't an Activity. 07-29
>   00:39:59.113: E/Ads(8849): Could not initialize AdView: AdView was
>   initialized with a Context that wasn't an Activity. 07-29
>   00:39:59.113: W/dalvikvm(8849): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40da9390) 07-29 00:39:59.133:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8849): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 07-29 00:39:59.133:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8849): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.clickvote.app/com.clickvote.app.WebViewActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error
>   inflating class com.google.ads.AdView 07-29 00:39:59.133:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)
>   07-29 00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
>   07-29 00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151) 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
>   07-29 00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 07-29 00:39:59.133:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-29 00:39:59.133:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
>   07-29 00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796) 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-29 00:39:59.133:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8849): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
>   07-29 00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613) 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
>   07-29 00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):     at
>   com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.setCustomView(ActionBarImpl.java:310)
>   07-29 00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   com.clickvote.app.WebViewActivity.onCreate(WebViewActivity.java:45)
>   07-29 00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066) 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
>   07-29 00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
>   07-29 00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   ... 11 more 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 07-29 00:39:59.133:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):     ... 20 more 07-29 00:39:59.133:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8849): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could
>   not initialize AdView: AdView was initialized with a Context that
>   wasn't an Activity. 07-29 00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:402) 07-29 00:39:59.133:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   at
>   com.google.ads.AdView.(SourceFile:125) 07-29 00:39:59.133:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   ... 23 more 07-29 00:39:59.133:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8849): Caused by: com.google.ads.internal.b: AdView
>   was initialized with a Context that wasn't an Activity. 07-29
>   00:39:59.133: E/AndroidRuntime(8849):     at
>   com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:389) 07-29 00:39:59.133:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(8849):   ... 24 more

Comment: The stack trace suggests you're trying to set the `AdView` as a custom view to the `ActionBar` (based on `ActionBarImpl.setCustomView(...)` - is that the case? If so, I suppose the 'themed context' that the ActionBar internally uses to inflate views, is not necessarily an `Activity`. You could try inflating the view yourself in an `Activity` and call `setCustomView(View view)` (as opposed to `setCustomView(int resId)`, which is what you're probably using right now).

Comment: thanks for the comment. i have not put any admob code in my activity, since i run the code from the layout xml.  

This is how my activity starts 




`
public class WebViewActivity extends DroidGap {

 public static String LOG_TAG = "name";

 private Dialog mLoadingDialog;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.ab);
  getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
  getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, based on your comment I'm going to post the earlier suggestion as an answer with some sample code, since, as you pointed out, you're quite new to Android.

Your current code:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends DroidGap {
    public static String LOG_TAG = "name";
    private Dialog mLoadingDialog;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.ab); // <-- !!
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Basically you should try to rewrite the line indicated above. Rather than delegating the custom view inflation to the `ActionBar`, inflate it yourself to ensure that an `Activity` context is used. Like so:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends DroidGap {
    public static String LOG_TAG = "name";
    private Dialog mLoadingDialog;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View customActionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ab, null, false);
        getActionBar().setCustomView(customActionBarView);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

That should (probably) get rid of the exception you're currently seeing. I didn't validate or try to run the snippet above, so be aware of any typos. If you're still experiencing the same problem after this, give me a nudge and I'll take a better look.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried the code you provided- but still having the same issue. What confuses me is that the admob is decleared via the xml and basically no code is used in the activity for admob.

Comment: And you're sure you removed the call that said `setCustomView(R.layout.ab)`? Perhaps it'd be worth ammending your question with some of the relevant code. Regarding your confusion: an `AdView` is a rather self-contained component, which is why, as a developer, you basically don't have to write any code against it.

Comment: yes i set the .setCustomView(customActionBarView); instead and same issue. Thanks for the info, thats what i was thinking and confused me why the simple xml integration is causing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading your error:

```
 AdView was initialized with a Context that wasn't an Activity
```

Comment: i did. any help on this ? Im really new at doing this

Comment: This is considered an answer, because it means that the Context that he is passing to the AdView is **NOT** coming from an Activity. Which is implying that the author needs to revisit his code to ensure its coming from an Activity.